# Converting varchar to datetime type

Tags: mysql

I need help with converting `varchar` type column which is having date time values to `DATETIME` type and I need only the Time part from it. i.e. I've a column with values like:

```
Verified_date
04/04/2013 03:17:08 PM
05/04/2013 10:10:13 AM
04/04/2013 03:45:15 PM
```

I need only the time part, i.e,

```
Time
03:17:08 PM
10:10:13 AM
03:45:15 PM
```

Comment: To be sure : you have multiple date in a single varchar ?

Comment: I'm doing 
Select Time(STR_TO_DATE((verify_time), '%d/%m/%Y %T')) from tbl
By doing it, I'm getting time part but not the AM/PM

Comment: @KrishnaKumar do you wish to process it as date, or do you just need it as a string

Comment: @KrishnaKumar So? Does it not get what you want? If it does, feel free to post as answer and accept it.

Comment: @Ajo - I need to process it as date

Comment: @tombom - I'm not getting AM/PM part of time

Comment: @KrishnaKumar did you try the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query using [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fdate-format):

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(('04/04/2013 03:17:08 PM'), '%d/%m/%Y %r '), '%r')
```

This statement will give you the required formatted date as `03:17:08 PM`.

You can view the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2976/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, just add ending formatting -

```
SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE('04/04/2013 03:17:08 PM', '%d/%c/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'));
+----------+
| 15:17:08 |
+----------+
```

One more simple solution -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('04/04/2013 03:17:08 PM', ' ', -2);
+-------------+
| 03:17:08 PM |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Would the second solution give a date/time entity?

Comment: For standard given strings - yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y %r'), '%r') from your_table;
```

Refer [date-and-time-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: This doesn't give the AM/PM tag

Comment: gives null as the result

Comment: Use date_format then. Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: i already have used it.. I was just pointing out that your query seemed wrong